# Identify these dice with letters

Tags: identify-this-game, identify-this-game-piece

[image: Four dice with coloured faced bearing letters]

Cleaning up our board games at my rental and found these four dice. They have kind of a Rubberized feel to them.

Die 1:

- Blue C
- Red D
- Purple S
- Yellow R
- Orange M
- Green N

Die 2:

- Blue H
- Red T
- Purple N
- Yellow A
- Orange R
- Green P

Die 3:

- Blue I
- Red J
- Purple L
- Yellow D
- Orange S
- Green G

Die 4:

- Blue V
- Red P
- Purple F
- Yellow E
- Orange B
- Green M

Comment: Interesting! Despite having only 24 faces, some of the letters are duplicated. It could indicate that some other dice are missing. Notably absent is the vowel O.

Answer (score 3):

I think these dice are not from a board game but from an early-education (preschool, kindergarten, first grade) instructional toy.

The [Panda Brothers Spelling Games](https://web.archive.org/web/20220723015727/https://www.amazon.com/Panda-Brothers-Matching-Letter-Game/dp/B08YXTQZLL/) and [Eeci Matching Letter Toy](https://web.archive.org/web/20220723015901/https://www.amazon.com/Eeci-Spelling-Preschool-Kindergarten-Educational/dp/B09832RWWN/) each come with eight one-inch (~2.5cm) cubes. Each cube has six different letters on six differently colored faces. The toy also comes with a deck of cards, each containing an illustrated three- or four-letter vocabulary word such as BIRD or WORM or TOP. The object of the "game" is to use the cubes to spell out the word on the card.

The games described above come with wooden cubes that do not look exactly like the ones in your image, but I found a [set of six cubes on Etsy](https://web.archive.org/web/20220723015033/https://www.etsy.com/listing/1013058370/six-sharp-oversized-colorful-letter-dice) that do look exactly like yours. The seller describes them as "Six Sharp Oversized Colorful Letter Dice" and highlights them as "Vintage" but does not identify where they came from.

[image: six colored letter cubes]

The visible portions of the Etsy cubes show these letter combinations:

Cube 1 (your Die 2):

- blue H
- orange R
- yellow A

Cube 2:

- red Y
- yellow B
- (unknown) H

Cube 3:

- orange C
- yellow L
- purple Z

Cube 4 (your Die 3):

- blue I
- purple L

Cube 5 (your Die 4):

- purple F
- yellow B
- blue? V

Cube 6 (your Die 1):

- purple S
- green? N
- yellow M